Twisted Hurewicz theorem
Let $X$ be a space. I am wondering if the following is true:
If for any local system $M$ on $X$ (pointwise isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$), $\tilde H_p(X; M) = 0$ for $p \leq n$, then $X$ is $n$-connected.
Is there a reference for this?
I encountered this in "A Generalization of a theorem of Vogtmann", a 1987 paper by Ruth Charney, where $X$ is the simplicial complex associated to a poset.

take your local system to be $C_*(\tilde{X})$ the universal cover as a $\mathbb Z\pi_1(X)$ module

This is false as stated. Let me assume that $X$ is connected, fix $x_0\in X$. Then, $H_1(X;\mathbb{Z})=0$ is equivalent, by the Hurewicz theorem, to $\pi_1(X,x_0)^{ab}=0$. This implies that any homomorphism $\pi_1(X,x_0)\rightarrow\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial, so that any local system that is pointwise isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial. Thus, the condition is automatically satisfied for $n=1$, but there are non-trivial perfect groups, so $X$ is not necessarily $1$-connected. For a concrete example, you can take $X$ to be the Poincaré dodecahedral sphere.
Edit: In case you allow arbitrary local coefficients, the answer is positive. Let me assume that $X$ is connected as before and that we may apply covering space theory (e.g. after taking a CW-approximation). Let $\pi=\pi_1(X,x_0)$. An element$x\in\pi$ generates a cyclic subgroup $\pi^{\prime}=\langle x\rangle\le\pi$, which induces a $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$-module, i.e. local system, $\mathbb{Z}[\pi/\pi^{\prime}]$ and a covering space $X^{\prime}\rightarrow X$. Then, we have $H_{\bullet}(X,\mathbb{Z}[\pi/\pi^{\prime}])=H_{\bullet}(X^{\prime},\mathbb{Z})$ (this is the topological interpretation of Shapiro's lemma) and in particular
$$0=H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}[\pi/\pi^{\prime}])=H_1(X^{\prime},\mathbb{Z})=\pi_1(X^{\prime},x_0^{\prime})^{ab}=\pi^{\prime}.$$
Thus, $x=0$. This element was arbitrary, so we obtain $\pi=0$, i.e. $X$ is simply connected, as desired. The cases for $n\ge2$ now follow from the usual Hurewicz theorem (in particular, allowing local coefficients only matters in dimension $1$).

Thank you! What about if I say "for any local system"?

@Mathis I've edited to address this case.
